# error: cannot find symbol (resultSetToTableModel)

Tags: java, swing, jar

Have a error, already added a jar rs2xml.jar but when project clean and build show this error- error: cannot find symbol
                jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
 don't understand that, please help me.

```
private void productCodeKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    String tf=productCode.getText();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Result rt = null;
    Connection con = getCon();
    try {
        if(tf.matches("^[0-9]+$")){
            String query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE ProductCode="+tf;
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));//error show here
        }else{
            String query1 = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE ProductName LIKE'%"+tf+"%'";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query1);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));// error show here
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
    try {
        if(ps!=null){
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you put the jar? did you add it to build path? what are you using for building?

Comment: put the jar in the libraries, also using ide netbeans.

Comment: did you import DBUtils in your class

Comment: yes, import DbUtils and even mport another -`import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;`

Answer (score 1):

Remove 
private Object DBUtils
And import instead
net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils